# Using an XML String to Insert into Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, xml, database, oracle

I have parsed (not sure if that is the correct terminology) a set of data into an xml string so that its something like this:

```
    <Data>
    <Books DataType = 'String' Values = 'Hello World', 'Hi'..../>
    ....
    </Data>
```

However, I now want to 'INSERT' that set of data into an oracle database using SQL. Everything I looked up uses DOM or some kind of document builder that I dont want/need in my program. The closest thing I have found is CLOB.

Is there any special methods that I can use in **JAVA** that would help me?

Comment: you can read your xml into variables using xpath and then insert? It can become complicated if your xml has varying layouts, but if your xml has a standard layout it's pretty usefull

Comment: you can use jaxb to get java object from your xml and work on it.

Comment: thank you guys, I will try both ways and get back to you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you store them into Strings ?
[How to store unlimited characters in Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976154/how-to-store-unlimited-characters-in-oracle-11g)

Or you can try mix JPA and JAX-B with somthing like this :

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Book {
...
}
```

and

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Data {    
    private List<Book> books;
...
}
```

Comment: ill gladly look into this too! however, I also wanted to keep the program simple